# View from the xib file is not showing/opening

Tags: iphone, interface-builder

Im having strange problem.. Im trying to open a View in the Xib file..
when I double click it.. I am not getting anything ...
I don't see the view..
but when I run the App ... view is there..
whats wrong why I can't see the view ???
plz help...

Thanks in advance..

Comment: -1 Unclear. When you double click what? What do you expect to see? Do you want it to appear in the simulator or in IB?

Answer (score 0):

When you open the xib, are there more than 1 views in it ?  Maybe you're in the wrong view.
You can also select it in the window that shows all the objects in the xib.